# Late Binding UserForm Functions

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

I have 2 userforms:

```
Userform1
Userform2
```

They both have the function `UpdateFields`, which is implemented differently in each.
I have 3rd function that takes as input a user form and tries to call the `UpdateField` function:

```
Public Sub ThirdFunction(Byref objForm as Form)
   'trying to do this
    objForm.UpdateFields
End Sub
```

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: change objForm type to Object. Form is the base clase your forms inherit from so your own UpdateFields is not known to Form.

Comment: I tried that, It didn't work

Comment: ok I just checked this - it does work with type as Object (for me). Double check your scope on the UpdateFields function.

Comment: You could use early binding `(ByRef objForm as MSForms.UserForm)`

Comment: @DavidZemens am I wrong in thinking that that wouldn't expose any custom methods on his forms?

Comment: @Cor_Blimey good catch, I was not following closely :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below works for me. You indicate it does not for you. Can you explain a little more any differences from the rough set-up I have below? That would help to narrow down the problem.

In a standard module:

```
Sub UpdateBoth()
    FrmUpdate Form_Table1
    FrmUpdate [Form_Copy Of Table1]
End Sub

Sub FrmUpdate(frm As Object)
    frm.UpdateFields
End Sub
```

In a form's code-behind (called Form_Table1):

```
Public Function UpdateFields()
    Debug.Print "Form 1 Update"
End Function
```

In another form's code-behind (called [Form_Copy of Table1]):

```
Public Function UpdateFields()
    Debug.Print "Form 2 Update"
End Function
```

Output:
Form 1 Update
Form 2 Update

Comment: It works, thanks. I had the functions set as private :)

Comment: @VBAProgrammer I do that all the time ;)